# Disable vibration on RecyclerView item drag

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-vibration

I am implementing a RecyclerView with drag and drop functionality using ItemTouch.Callback. Right now the device vibrates slightly when I start dragging a ViewHolder.

How can I stop the device vibration when the drag begins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by disabling haptic feedback of my ViewHolder.

```
public CustomViewHolder(View view)
{
    super(view);

    view.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
}
```

You can also disable it for any view in XML by using the following.

```
android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
```